# dropzone amd requirejs issue

Tags: javascript, requirejs, dropzone.js

I'm new to `requirejs` and I have a problem loading `dropzonejs` (http://www.dropzonejs.com/) as an **AMD** .

My `requirejs` config is:

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: 'js/MV'
,paths: {
            ,jquery: '../libs/jquery-latest'
    handlebars: '../plugins/handlebars'
    ,scrolltofixed: '../plugins/scrolltofixed'
    ,logout: '../logout'
    ,dropzone: '../plugins/dropzoneAmdModule'
    }
});
```

When I try to load the `dropzone` module with

```
function _activateDropzone(){ 
  require(['dropzone'], function(dropzone){
     var pippo = new Dropzone({ //..config 

     });  
  });
}
```

it `logs`

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Dropzone is not defined
```

even if I'm loading the *dropzone-amd-module* . 
Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With RequireJS you have to use the return value in the callback function. In your example you are using `dropzone` (lower case) as the module return value, but in the code you then use `Dropzone` (upper case). I think this should work:

```
function _activateDropzone(){ 
  require(['dropzone'], function(Dropzone){
     var pippo = new Dropzone({ //..config 

     });  
  });
}
```

dropzone-amd-module is detecting that is is being used within AMD loader and instead of adding Dropzone to the global scope it returns a local value to the module loader.